# How to make a DataTables filter to work across rows

Tags: datatables

Let's say I have a dataset like

```
$('table').DataTable({
    data: [
        ['First set'],
        ['Starting another set'],
        ['  Some stuff'],
        ['  More stuff'],
        ['  Last row in the set'],
        ['Last set']
    ],
  columns: [
  null
  ],
  ordering: false
 });
```

(https://jsfiddle.net/Lg8sjt2h/2/

How can I make the search by term 'Last' match all rows in the set (indented)? Custom filter functions get a single row and can't work on all dataset.

I can't combine each set in a single row since it will make the row heights uneven and break the DataTables scroller (and the virtual scrolling is necessary).

Comment: Can you please create an demo on https://jsfiddle.net ? That will definitely help in solving your problem.

Comment: @Gyrocode.com, added a jsfiddle link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would strongly suggest to implement child rows (see [this example](http://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html)) instead of using indentation as your only means of representing hierarchy.

However if that is not an option, you can use a trick with hidden column that will be searchable but not visible. You would need to preprocess your data and concatenate data from parent and all child rows into second column data.

Probably this is not best solution but it works.

**HTML:**

```
<table width="100%">
    <thead><tr><th></th><th></th></tr></thead>
</table>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$('table').DataTable({
    data: [
        ['First set', 'First set'],
        ['Starting another set', 'Starting another set Some stuff More stuff Last row in the set'],
        ['  Some stuff', 'Starting another set  Some stuff More stuff Last row in the set'],
        ['  More stuff', 'Starting another set  Some stuff More stuff Last row in the set'],
        ['  Last row in the set', 'Starting another set Some stuff More stuff Last row in the set'],
        ['Last set', 'Last set']
    ],
    columns: [
        null, 
        { visible: false }
    ],
    ordering: false
});
```

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lg8sjt2h/4/) for code and demonstration.

Try searching for `stuff`, `set` or `last`.

Comment: Thanks, I wanted to do the same but was hesitating due to the size of dataset. I want to filter it on the browser side and looking up in the pre-processed data is not free, but it seems I have no better (obvious) choice.